# Owl Carousel keyboard navigation with multiple carousel

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, owl-carousel

Is there a way to fix keyboard tabbing with the left and right keys when multiple owl carousels are on a page?

The issue is although the keyboard tabbing works - also it affects all the owl carousels on the page instead of the one focused on. So all the owl carousels and moving.

Is it because of this function. Is there a more specific way of calling just the current owl carousel instead of:     `document.documentElement`

Here's the demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRQZVK

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].